# Update app already installed a package with the same name with a conflicting signature

Tags: android

I followed these steps::

Export the application -> sign (Proguard) keyStore -> and install version:

I get this error :

> Application not installed:
>
> already installed a package with the same name with a conflicting signature
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/do9nv.png

I have installed it with the same password I signed the application,
 but I skip this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an update over Google Play?

If not then make sure you have selected the correct key (Since you may have multiple keys with the same password). Failing that, you could always delete the currently installed app which would erase the conflicting issue.

Comment: App not hosted on google play, is hosted on a website, do not understand what you mean with the correct key, I only have one key, how to select the key? URGENT ISSUE

Comment: Try to uninstall the application that is causing the conflict.